# How to give command to CMD from JAVA SWING programe(Print command to cmd from JAVA Swing)

Tags: java, swing, printing, cmd

I am making POS which have comport printer. I created one text file and I want to give to the printer. I know the cmd command(print data.txt /d:com2) but how to give this command to CMD using java program?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about stdin/stdout, them just

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("print data.txt /d:com2").waitFor();
```